# How to to display all value from table without one record MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table "number" that contains values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
how to display all data from table "number" without display data containing value 6

Comment: (Try answering *how to display a record from table "number" not containing value 6*.)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let those values 1, 2, ... are under the column named as **data**

then the select query is

```
SELECT * FROM number WHERE data != 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from number where Column_X <> 6
```